# Get current year and month (and next month) in this format YYYYMM in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date, time

How do I get the current date and month in Ruby in a specific format?

If today is June, 8th of 2012, I want to get `201206`.

And also, I would like to be able to get the next month from the one we are in, taking into account that in **201212**, the next month would be **201301**.

Comment: google for Time#strftime

Comment: tokland I know I can do this  Time.now.strftime("%Y%m") - but how do I get the next month?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your edit.  It now produces your desired date.

Answer (score 39):

I'd do it like this:

```
require 'date'
Date.today.strftime("%Y%m")
#=> "201206"
(Date.today>>1).strftime("%Y%m")
#=> "201207"
```

The advantage of [Date#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) is that it automatically takes care of certain things for you:

```
Date.new(2012,12,12)>>1
#=> #<Date: 2013-01-12 ((2456305j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 17):

Current month:

```
date = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m")
```

Next month:

```
if Time.now.month == 12
  date = Time.now.year.next.to_s + "01"
else
  date = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m").to_i + 1
end
```

Answer (score 7):

As of Ruby 2, "next_month" is a method on Date:

```
require "Date"

Date.today.strftime("%Y%m")
# => "201407"

Date.today.next_month.strftime("%Y%m")
# => "201408"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
require 'date'
d=Date.today                    #current date
d.strftime("%Y%m")              #current date in format
d.next_month.strftime("%Y%m")   #next month in format
```

Answer (score 2):

use http://strfti.me/ for that kind of stuff

```
strftime "%Y%m"
```

Comment: but how do I get the next month?

Comment: well, you have to feed strftime with a Time first. Like `Time.now.strftime "%Y%m"`

Comment: I know that. But how do I get the next month?

Comment: You could put that in a loop and iterate through the months if you like but I'm not entirely sure what you're up to.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 2 Plus and rails 4 plus.

By using below functions you can find required results.

```
Time.now #current time according to server timezone
Date.today.strftime("%Y%m") # => "201803"

Date.today.next_month.strftime("%Y%m") # => "201804"
```